# ICryptoTransform decryptor C# equivalent in reactjs

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, cryptography, cryptojs

I am migrating from .net core to reactjs and need to Decrypt Hash to object. I stuck here where results are not equal. Here is the code of .net.
Note: cipherText length is 656 I can't paste such a long array here.

```
byte[] cipherText = [132, 185, 138, 129, 38, 216, 49, 48, 25, 139, 187, 146, 67, 234, 194, 143, 252, 214, 245, 230, 30, 238, 235, 53, 155, 136, 0, 112, 76, 27, 205, 84, 124, 250, 74, 114, 208, 227, 148, 135, 112, 168, 171, 73, 45, 122, 31, 248, 186, 80, 148, 143, 251, 216, 90, 152, 138, 130, 148, 199, 178, 151, 151, 195, 252, 43, 67, 183, 45, 24, 228, 73, 208, 249, 155, 36, 78, 232, 210, 20, 235, 109, 206, 245, 180, 28, 227, 32, 202, 143, 255, 110, 128, 38, 101, 174, 253, 80, 171, 201......]
plaintext = null;
byte[] Key = [56, 63, 82, 186, 73, 8, 112, 110, 129, 185, 157, 192, 163, 160, 120, 215, 52, 254, 252, 189, 25, 82, 43, 15, 87, 98, 48, 193, 21, 44, 6, 163]0: 561: 632: 823: 1864: 735: 86: 1127: 1108: 1299: 18510: 15711: 19212: 16313: 16014: 12015: 21516: 5217: 25418: 25219: 18920: 2521: 8222: 4323: 1524: 8725: 9826: 4827: 19328: 2129: 4430: 631: 163];
byte[] IV = [200, 97, 110, 6, 23, 248, 144, 210, 223, 167, 67, 64, 125, 96, 136, 201]

        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I decrypt byte array with cryptojs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, Here is the solution:

```
var strHexWA = (CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(cipherText)));             
            var KeyWA = (CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(Key)));
            var IVWA = (CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(IV)));
            var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
                ciphertext: strHexWA
            }, KeyWA, {
                iv: IVWA,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
            }); 
            var plaintext = decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);            
            return plaintext;
```